# Keep the all the elements at the same place

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering because I am coding through multiple screen sizes and making a game that requires `event.pageX` and smaller screen sizes mean squishing everything as well as bigger screen sizes that push everything outwards. Is there a way to keep everything all positioned into one place so if you change screen sizes it is still positioned the same?

Comment: How about you post a screenshot at least, so people could understand what you are talking about! And answer to your question - of course there is a way. create a responsive design, rather than 'pixelated'.

Comment: It's just that when I change to a bigger screen everything gets pushed outwards and then event.pageX is messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few css tricks that can helps you with your problem:

- You can define body width and height, that will prevent window changes on resize, for example:

  body {
    width: 800px
    height: 800px
  }
- Avoid using percents in element position defenition
- Css `position : absolute` can make your element behave independently from other elements. `position : fixed` allows you ignore even user scroll if you need this. [(more info)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

small jsfiddle with some examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/qc3p2d5h/2/